# Collapsing Coordinator layout when scrolled up by 25%

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to automatically collapse the RelativeLayout when it is scrolled up by 25% or when scrolled down by 75%.

This is my code for the layout is here:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24px"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/userName"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="27sp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/ask"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/name"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/collapsible_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:text="Button text"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I've tried to add a few tags for doing it, but none of them seem to work. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your `layout_scrollFlags` to the `AppBarLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary">
```